# Call out sign_out method as a background task using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am building a rails app where I have to auto-logout few users if the current time crosses 6PM and other users if current time crosses 7PM. I am using devise for authentication. I did not find any solution using devise. Devise just has a single timeout_in parameter for inactivity.

I also tried with delayed_job. But during the asynchronous task execution, session hash is not recognized.

Is there some kind of obvious solution that I am missing ?

Comment: Devise uses signed cookies. You could just add expiration to cookies. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the expiration period dynamically on Devise as of version 1.5.2.
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise (...), :timeoutable

  def timeout_in
    if should_logout_at_19
      timeout_period_for 19
    elsif should_logout_at_18
      timeout_period_for 18
    else
    ...
    end
  end

  # period in seconds until next session expiration hour.
  def timeout_period_for(given_hour)
    next_time = if Time.now.hour > given_hour
      Date.tomorrow.to_time.change(hour: given_hour)
    else
      Date.today.to_time.change(hour: given_hour)
    end
    next_time - Time.now
  end

  def should_logout_at_19
    # user criteria to logout at 7 PM
  end

end
```